# Angular 5+ component HTMLElement.style.display suddenly give cannot read property 'style' of 'null'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a angular 5.2.0/Typescript 2.6.2 and Node 8.5.0 app that uses

```
HTML:
    <button mat-raised-button id="submitDescription" class="submit-class" [ngStyle]="{'color': 
     themeFontColor()}" (click)="submit(false)">{{submit}}</button>
 ...

Component.ts:
 ....
 submitBtn: HTMLElement;
 .....
 .....
 ngOnInit{
 ......
 .......
 } 
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitDescription');
    this.viewLoaded = true;
   
  }
```

Now suddenly the line

```
 this.submitBtn.style.display = 'none';
```

produce this error

```
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

The similar code is in two components now without any modification to the code I am getting this error in both places which lead me to believe something external has changed but I have no idea what. Could Service Workers be causing this problem?

EDIT:

```
HTML:
  <input [ngClass]='{"has-error":(wholeDescriptionRef.invalid && submitted), "has-success":(wholeDescriptionRef.valid && submitted)}' type="text" class="form-control query-input content-light-blue-color" id="wholeDescription" placeholder="{{ezzy.LOCALIZATION.requestPlaceHolder}}"
            [ngStyle]="{'background-color': ezzy.getThemeSecondaryColor()}" name="wholeDescription" [(ngModel)]="wholeDescription" maxlength="100" #wholeDescriptionRef="ngModel" required (keyup)="submitOnEnter($event)">
        <button mat-raised-button #submitDescription class="submit-class" [ngStyle]="{'color': ezzy.getThemeFontColor()}" (click)="submit(false)">{{ezzy.LOCALIZATION.submit}}</button>
        <span [hidden]="!ezzy.supportsSpeech" (click)="ezzy.startDictation(this, 'wholeDescription', 'submit', 'wholeDescription', 'submitDescription')" class="input-group-addon cursor-pointer icon-style" [ngStyle]="{'color':'#ffffff','background-color': ezzy.getThemeHeaderColor(), 'border': ezzy.getThemeBorderColor(), 'border-collapse': 'collapse'}">
        <i class="fa fa-microphone fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Comment: You should use Viewchild rather than document.getElementById

Comment: @pc_coder ..yes I could but I don't see how it would answer my question. Things don't stop working without a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer lies in tsconfig.json file...(credit to this answer https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9813)

```
  ......
  ........
  "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ]
```

Where "target": "es2015" should be set to "es5"